# Replacing elements in the selected object's material name

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to alter the filepath of a material's texture and then also alter the name of said material. However, I would like to limit the name change it to the selected object's material only, so as to not affect other materials in the scene which also include the word.

From cannibalising other scripts, This is what I have so far (I am no python-coder, but any help would be appreciated) but I get 'Material' is not iterable

```
import bpy

for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    for img in bpy.data.images:
         img.filepath = img.filepath.replace('Red1', 'Red2')
         img.reload()
for mat in bpy.context.active_object.active_material:
    mat.name = mat.name.replace('RED1', 'RED2')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    for slot in ob.material_slots:
        if slot.material:
            if slot.material.node_tree:
                for node in slot.material.node_tree.nodes:
                    if img := getattr(node, 'image', None):
                        new_path = img.filepath_raw.replace('Red1', 'Red2')
                        img.filepath_raw = new_path
                        img.reload()
            slot.material.name = slot.material.name.replace('RED1', 'RED2')
```